# Using String.Contains inside a LookupSet in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, reporting-services

I've got two datasets called A and B. A has one field called Paper. B has two fields called Subject and Grade.

The data inside those fields looks something like:

```
+---------+-------+       +-----------------------------+
| Subject | Grade |       |            Paper            |
+---------+-------+       +-----------------------------+
| English | A     |       | English Literature Autumn 1 |
| Maths   | D     |       | Further Maths Spring 2      |
| Physics | F     |       | Physics                     |
+---------+-------+       +-----------------------------+
```

The LookupSet I normally use looks like:

```
=LookupSet(Fields!Paper.Value, Fields!Subject.Value, Fields!Grade.Value, "B")
```

But of course it only returns *F* as *Physics* is the only field that is identical. I need something that will return the rest of the grades. I've tried:

```
=LookupSet(Fields!Paper.Value, Fields!Subject.Value.IndexOf(Fields!Subject.Value) >= 0, Fields!Grade.Value, "B")
```

Or

```
=LookupSet(Fields!Paper.Value, Fields!Subject.Paper.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(Fields!Subject.Value), Fields!Grade.Value, "B")
```

Is there a way I can achieve it without altering the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the source is SQL Server, you can do this in T-SQL using LIKE.

#### SQL Example

```
WITH
subject_grades
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'English', 'A')
    , ( 'Maths', 'D')
    , ( 'Physics', 'F')
    ) tbl ([Subject], [Grade]) 
)
, 
subject_papers
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'English Literature Autumn 1')
    , ( 'Further Maths Spring 2')
    , ( 'Physics')
    ) tbl ([Paper]) 
)
SELECT
      sp.Paper
    , sg.Grade
FROM 
    subject_papers AS sp
    LEFT JOIN subject_grades AS sg ON sp.[Paper] LIKE '%' + sg.[Subject] + '%'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2019d6754ccf91f01bbacdffd92e4193)

#### Results

[image: results]

Comment: Thank you this solves the problem. Looks like doing this sort of thing is always easier/possible in SQL as opposed to obscure vb.net functions

Comment: I find it's a bit easier to have SQL Server do most of the work and just view the results in SSRS.